# CSS grid template full width row

Tags: css, css-grid

I am aiming for this kind of grid layout:

```
    +-----------------+-----------------+
    |    column A1    |    column A2    |
    +-----------------+-----------------+
    |              column B             |
    +-----------------------------------+
```

Where `column A1` and `column A2` have 50% of the horizontal page width and `column B` is full width.

I believe I have misinterpreted content areas, believing that . means item and the multiple eventAreas = double width?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 500px 500px / auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: '. .  eventArena eventArena';
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: eventArena;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <p class="titleBlock">Over 400 events</p>
    <p class="descriptionBlock">Proin ac lobortis arcu, a vestibulum augue. Vivamus ipsum neque, facilisis vel mollis vitae, mollis nec ante. Quisque ali- quam dictum condim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <p class="titleBlockRight">Join a society</p>
    <p class="descriptionBlockRight">Proin ac lobortis arcu, a vestibulum augue. Vivamus ipsum neque, facilisis vel mollis vitae, mollis nec ante. Quisque ali- quam dictum condim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <p class="titleBlock">Book a space</p>
    <p class="descriptionBlock"> Proin ac lobortis arcu, a vestibulum augue. Vivamus ipsum neque, facilisis vel mollis vitae, mollis nec ante. Quisque ali- quam dictum condim.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like [This](https://jsfiddle.net/dp12w73z/) ?

Comment: your answer is correct. u should put it as ANSWER

Comment: I'm not sure, if that's it he wants or like the answer

Comment: Hi Manic, I have just edited your question. Please have a go at rephrasing the last sentence to make it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: You're a star thanks. Got the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this.

Each template area "row" has to be separated by quotes.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-areas: "... ..." 
                       "eventArena eventArena";
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: eventArena;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <p class="titleBlock">Over 400 events</p>
    <p class="descriptionBlock">Proin ac lobortis arcu, a vestibulum augue. Vivamus ipsum neque, facilisis vel mollis vitae, mollis nec ante. Quisque ali- quam dictum condim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <p class="titleBlockRight">Join a society</p>
    <p class="descriptionBlockRight">Proin ac lobortis arcu, a vestibulum augue. Vivamus ipsum neque, facilisis vel mollis vitae, mollis nec ante. Quisque ali- quam dictum condim.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
    <p class="titleBlock">Book a space</p>
    <p class="descriptionBlock"> Proin ac lobortis arcu, a vestibulum augue. Vivamus ipsum neque, facilisis vel mollis vitae, mollis nec ante. Quisque ali- quam dictum condim.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i thinks he wants three columns on the same row. first omment has the answer

Comment: @Alejo_Blue No...he clearly doesn't since he's only defined two columns. See the layout suggested in the question.

Comment: maybe ur right since he just updated the question. my apologies

Comment: Brilliant thank you. That was what I wanted, sorry for the confusion